# Can I use numpy.maximum() or something similar with ortools for optimimization?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I am looking to model an inventory policy and am stumped on how to model an ending inventory that cannot be negative.  I would like to use a function such as numpy.maximum() to set any negative numbers to 0, but this doesn't seemto work with ortools.

Here's a simplified example.  I appreciate your suggestions!

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
day = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
item_id = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
increase = [4, 0, 4, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]
decrease = [2, 2, 2, 5, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(day, item_id, increase, decrease)),
                     columns=['day', 'item_id', 'increase', 'decrease'])
my_df['change'] = my_df.increase - my_df.decrease
my_df = my_df.set_index(['item_id', 'day'])
index_item_day = list(zip(my_df.reset_index().item_id, my_df.reset_index().day))
change = {(i, d): my_df.loc[i, d]['change'] for i, d in index_item_day}
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP') # or ('GLOP')
percent_var = solver.NumVar(0, 1, 'percent_var')
end_inv = {}
for i, d in index_item_day:
    end_inv[i, d] = solver.NumVar(-solver.infinity(), solver.infinity(), 'end_inv')
for i, d in index_item_day:
#     if d==1:
    solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == change[i, d] * percent_var)
#     solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == np.maximum(end_inv[i, d-1] + change[i, d] * percent_var, 0))
#     else:
#         solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == np.maximum(0, change[i, d] * percent_var))
    
# The objective function is to maximize the % given the ending inventory constraint
solver.Maximize(percent_var)
status = solver.Solve()
if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL or status == pywraplp.Solver.FEASIBLE:
    print('Maximum % = ', solver.Objective().Value())
else:
    print('There was not an optimal solution')
item = []
day = []
actual_change = []
e_inv = []
# pos = []
for i, d in index_item_day:
    item.append(i)
    day.append(d)
    actual_change.append(change[i, d] * percent_var.solution_value())
    e_inv.append(end_inv[i, d].solution_value())
supply_results_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(item, day, actual_change, e_inv)), 
                                 columns=['item', 'day', 'actual_change', 'ending_inventory'])
supply_results_df
```

The result here has negative ending_inventory:
[image]

However, if I try to add numpy.maximum(0, original equation), by commenting out the original line and bringing this one in, that doesn't change the negative ending_inventory values to 0:

```
    solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == change[i, d] * percent_var)
#     solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == np.maximum(change[i, d] * percent_var, 0))
```

If I move the 0 the first position rather than the 2nd position in np.maximum(), then all of the ending_inventory values are 0.

```
solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == np.maximum(0, change[i, d] * percent_var))
```

[image]

Comment: the logic in what you are trying to model isn't that clear...  if you have a negative change in inventory and multiply that by a ratio between zero and 1, how could you end up with a positive "end value"?  You seem to be missing the "starting inventory"???  to your question, max() and min() are non-linear functions and can't be used.  You could constrain `end_value` to be greater than 0, or just change the bounds on it to be {0, infinite}...

Comment: Starting inventory is the previous period's ending inventory, which is in there.

Comment: I'm trying slack variables right now as well, this is just a toy problem.  In the large data, I have predicted sales that exceed supply.  Obviously sales can't exceed supply, but I need the inventory number to stay positive.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: the constraint based on this statement does not include any ref to previous values, and cannot be positive as you describe if the daily change is negative:  `end_inv[i, d] == change[i, d] * percent_var`

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, in another version I wrote end_inv[i, d] = end_inv[i, d-1] + ...  `for i, d in index_item_day:
    if d==1:
        solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == change[i, d] * percent_var - slack[i, d])
    else:
        solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == end_inv[i, d-1] + change[i, d] * percent_var - slack[i, d])`  I updated this in the commented out section in the description now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a slack variable seemed to work!  I'll post an update here if I have any issues extending this to the larger model.

```
for i, d in index_item_day:
    if d==1:
        solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == change[i, d] * percent_var + slack[i, d])
    else:
        solver.Add(end_inv[i, d] == end_inv[i, d-1] + change[i, d] * percent_var + slack[i, d])
```

Comment: One additional change was needed: to add the slack to the objective function to ensure that the slack is minimized `solver.Maximize(percent_var - solver.Sum(slack[i, d] for i, d in index_item_day))`

Answer (score 1):

No, comparison operators between OR-Tools linear expressions (variables, constants, sums...) create python objects, not Boolean values.

Calling `__bool__` on them will raise an error when called on CP-SAT objects, or will silently return `True` on pywraplp objects.

You must use `AddMaximumEquality()` if you use the CP-SAT API. There are no max method in pywraplp.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm attempting to use a slack variable to consume the negative, and then to set the end_inv to (0, infinity).  I dn't have luck with this method yet either.